# Add div to Nokogiri XML NodeSet

Tags: html, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm just trying to add a "dummy" div into the head of this HTML snippet, and I've tried 100 ways and nothing is working.

This is what the `head` looks like when I pull it down:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Horraa</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
</head>
```

I just want to put in this dummy div:

```
<div> id='todd' class='{{customer.name}} {{shop.domain}}'</div>
```

So the end result is this

```
<head>
<div> id='todd' class='{{customer.name}} {{shop.domain}}'</div>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Horraa</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
</head>
```

This is my Nokogiri

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(todd)
head = page.css('head')
```

Head is now a `Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet`

This doesn't work

```
div = "<div> id='todd' class='{{customer.name}} {{shop.domain}}'</div>"
head.push(div)
```

Or this

```
div = "<div> id='todd' class='{{customer.name}} {{shop.domain}}'</div>"
update = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new('div', todd)
update['class'] = '{{customer.name}} {{shop.domain}}'
head.add_previous_sibling(update)
head << update
```

or this

```
head.add_next_sibling "<div> id='todd' class='{{customer.name}} {{shop.domain}}'</div>"
```

and I've tried 10 others, but this is getting long.. Where did I go astray?

Comment: Perhaps if your markup in `div` were valid it'd work better? You can't use `"<div>..."`, it needs to be `"<div..."`. You're terminating the tag prematurely so Nokogiri won't accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
html_string = "<div id='todd' class='{{customer.name}} {{shop.domain}}'></div>"
page.at('head').add_child(html_string)
```